# creating a derived class object with existing base class object?

Tags: c++, class, memory, object, derived-class

Is there a possibility of (or fast workaround for) creating an object defined as derived a class without creating base class object in memory; instead the derived object should refer to the actually existing object of base class ("take-over" its memory residence)? This is needed for speed reasons - creating new a derived object, copying data from base class object to it, and then destroying base object takes too much time.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to turn an instance of a base class X into an instance of derived class Y without copying? Are there any new fields introduced in the derived class?

Comment: i want to turn an instance of base class into instance of derived class but without creating base class object in memory - creating instance of derived class should use existing instance of base class as part of it in memory. and yes there are new fields. base class is a "memory saver" - it has only variables always needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get base object's data in a new derived object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498858/how-to-get-base-objects-data-in-a-new-derived-object)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider composition instead of inheritance in this case - it would be more natural.

Comment: thanks for ultra-fast answer :D but as i understand composition requires to include "part" class variable in "whole" class object and that is a problem cos i need "whole" class to be smallest as possible - even including a pointer to "part" class is too much - "whole" class (or base class in my question approach) is the memory saver, i'm talking about bytes here...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the `class` construct that is supported by the language. If you need something small and that flexible consider writing a `struct` and implementing your own `v-table`'s using function pointers. Much the same way as this is done for example in the Linux kernel. Note that object oriented programming can be done in almost any language, not necessarily one that supports it.

You could then switch the v-table pointer on the fly and possibly perform some `realloc` in order to add the fields that are required by the derived type.

In the end you could package all of this in a regular `class` that doesn't have any dynamic methods and just delegates all the calls to the described internal structure. This shouldn't impose any memory or computational overhead.

EDIT: Actually I guess `realloc` is not the way to go. This is a routine that engages the underlying operating system and requires a context switch. Almost always calling `copy` will be faster provided you have the appropriate memory block already allocated. If you're interested in speed, then maybe consider also implementing your own memory management or using one of the alternative implementation provided by libraries such as boost.

Comment: hmm... this may be it... i will look into implementing my own v-tables. but how to switch v-table on the fly? and i assume this all is possible in c++ yes?

Comment: I really mean mimicking the implementation of the built-in feature of the language. Typically classes have a pointer to a table of method implementations. Once a dynamic method is called, first the appropriate implementation is looked up in the v-table. Switching a v-table would in this case mean assigning a new value to the v-table pointer that is held in each instance. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you seem to want to do.

Consider:

```
   d1 = prestochango(b);
   d2 = prestochango(b);
   d1.blarf = waldo;
   // what value does d2.blarf now have?
```

Either d1 and d2 are distinct objects, including distinct b-substrates, or they are the same object.

Now, you MIGHT be able to FAKE it by making your b-substrate a static member of your d class.

Comment: i've made a typo in question: "...defined in derived..." should be "...defined as derived..." (already changed), sorry english is not my main language.       what i want: when creating an instance of derived class normally compiler creates base class and derived class variables in memory - i need other behaviour: instead of creating base class variables i need to "take-over" existing instance base class variables (so no need for destroying base class object and only creating derived class variables in memory)

Comment: At this point, I believe that it is not possible to do what you say you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamic call derived class, the v-table is indispensable.

So maybe you can implement the "base class" with no data member, and pass in data or pointer of data that your virtual functions need as argument during calling.

It'll save memory but cost more time.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create one version of a base class and have all objects inherit or be derived from the same instance, then you can declare things as static in the base class.  Static means one version of it for every instance of a class.

i.e.

```
class FooBase {
protected:
    static int IDCnt;
    static int ObjCnt;
    int ID;
public:
    FooBase();
    ~FooBase();
    virtual int GetID();
    virtual int GetObjCnt();
    virtual int GetIDCnt();
};
//implementation
int FooBase::IDCnt = 0; //need to init static vars
int FooBase::ObjCnt = 0;
FooBase::FooBase() { ID = IDCnt; IDCnt++; ObjCnt++; }
FooBase::~FooBase() { ObjCnt--; }
int FooBase::GetID() { return ID; }
int FooBase::GetObjCnt() { return ObjCnt; }
int FooBase::GetIDCnt() { return IDCnt; }

#include "FooBase.h"
class FooDerived : public FooBase {
      //blah

};
#include "FooDervied.h"

int main() {
FooDerived A;
FooDerived B;
cout << A.GetID() << ' ' << A.GetObjCnt() << ' ' << A.GetIDCnt() << endl;
cout << B.GetID() << ' ' << B.GetObjCnt() << ' ' << B.GetIDCnt() << endl;
if(true) {
   FooDerived C;
   cout << A.GetObjCnt() << ' ' << A.GetIDCnt() << ' ' << B.GetObjCnt << C.GetIDCnt() << endl;
}
cout << B.GetObjCnt() << '' << A.GetObjCnt() << ' ' << A.GetIDCnt() << ' ' << B.GetIDCnt << endl;

}
```

In this manner you don't declare a base class item, instead, the instance of base class is inherited through the static variables which basically means all `FooDerived` are looking at the same block of memory for `FooBase::IDCnt` and `FooBase::ObjCnt`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider Factory design pattern ?

Your base class only needs to know what kinda derived class you wanna create

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue